# SAML indendity propagation

Tags: saml-2.0

In my scenario I have the following architecture elements: 
- SAML secured Portal (Domain A) 
- User 
- SAML secured API( Domain B, so different domain than the portal) 
- an IdP
The user will login first to the portal, when not authenticated, the portal will redirect him to the identity provider to login. Once logged in to the IdP and hence to the Portal, the Portal will possess a SAML token identifying the user.

Now this portal will need to automatically call the API (present on another domain), and pass to it a SAML token identifying the user.  Problem is that the portal only posses the token that has been provided to him, and hence my question:

How can I propagate the identity of the user through the invocation chain?

For instance, is it possible to share same token between different relying parties? If yes, what are the constraints that the issued token should respect to make sure it can be "shared" by different entities?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One way could be that the portal rather than calling the API directly, instead should redirect the user to the API.

This way the API will find the user doesn't have a valid session, will redirect to the IdP where the user is already authenticated. The IdP will then redirect back to the API with the SAML response for the API.

This will all be transparent to the user, who will just see the result from the API.

Comment: Thanks.

But the API is a WS API. It does not have a User Interface. The response of the API will not make any sense as it is just XML. The portal will need to format it.